# Вопрос по поводу ввода данных

Tags: c#

В C# при вводе любого типа данных, в памяти всегда записывается только строка, я правильно понимаю? Дальше (по необходимости), нужно конвертировать в нужный тип? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: нет, не правильно понимаете. Память - это набор бит. Биты организованы в байты. Байты представляют собой данные. Тип данных C# в итоге представляет собой организованный набор байт.

Comment: Вы не поняли мой вопрос) К примеру, мне нужно проделать определенные операции с веденным числом, а затем вывести его. Когда я ввожу число с клавиатуры, С# превращает число в строку и дальнейшие манипуляции бесполезны, т.к. они предназначены для типа int (к примеру). Мне, для корректной работы  программы, нужно конвертировать число их строки в тип int и все. Я уже понял, что без конвертации типов не обойтись, но стало интересен мой вопрос выше.  @tym32167

Comment: C# ничего ни во что не превращает. Вы, видимо,читаете данные из консоли, которая данные вам может передать либо в виде кода нажатого символа, либо в виде введенной пользователем строки. Потому вы и считываете из консоли строку, а вот что дальше вы с этой строкой делать будете - это уже ваше дело, хотите - конвертируйте в целое число, хотите - в дату, если то, что ввел юзер, вообще во что то конвертируется.

Comment: Дело не в C#, а в консоли. Консоль принимает на вход строки или символы и соответственно отображает пользователю строки или символы. То есть когда изобретут консоль с подключением прямо к мозгу пользователя, то можно будет считывать данные в виде комбинаций значений синапсов, потом преобразовывать в числовые значения, делать вычисления, а затем снова отправлять в виде комбинации синапсов в мозг пользователя результат вычислений.

Comment: Ввод данных откуда? Почему это не указано в вопросе? Из разных источников можно читать по-разному.